# How to add a condition to read line by line and append text after each line

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I want to read each line and find if my line says " Project", then take the substring of that line (substring, 8 - Anything after the word Project) as an example and copy it to the end of each line for every row of line after the fact and up until a new line reads " Project". It should keep  looping until the end of my file. This is what I have so far. My script stops and only displays the first line that is being read.

```
   private void CreateFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            var list = new List<string>();

            using (var sr = new StreamReader("C:\\File1.txt"))
            {
                string line;

                if ((line = sr.ReadLine()) == " PROJECT")
                {

                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        list.Add(line + "DATA");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    list.Add(line);
                }
            }

            TextBox.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, list.ToArray());

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error has occurred" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe i have understood your requirement:

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader("C:\\File1.txt"))
{
    string line;
    string currentProject = null;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        int index = line.IndexOf(" PROJECT", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        if (index >= 0)
            currentProject = line.Substring(index + 9);
        else
            list.Add(string.Format("{0} {1}",line, currentProject));
    }
}
```

You have two `ReadLine` in the `if` which advances the reader to the next line.

Comment: Is this just giving you the line row your on? int index = line.IndexOf(" PROJECT", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

Comment: No it gives you the index of a sub-string in another string. In this case the position of PROJECT in the line. IndexOf returns -1 if the string was not found. I have used StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase to show you how you can search case-insensitively. By default. NET is case sensitive, that means Project!=PROJECT.

Comment: That makes sense, because I wanted to see the value of index and initially it showed 0, then it showed -1 and at that point I was a bit confused. Thanks for clearing that up.